# How to summon Acceleration due to Gravity in Mathematica 11?

Tags: units, physical-constants

## How to summon Acceleration due to Gravity in Mathematica 11?

[image]

seems like a simple thing but the documentation is no help.

Comment: It's `Quantity["StandardAccelerationOfGravity"]`, plain `"AccelerationOfGravity"` isn't universal.

Comment: Or to see the numeric value: `Quantity["StandardAccelerationOfGravity"] // UnitConvert`

Comment: You can also use `GeogravityModelData[GeoPosition[{40, -90}], "Magnitude"]` to  get the value at a given location. Or even at a given elevation in meters with  `GeogravityModelData[GeoPosition[{40, -90, 100000}], "Magnitude"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get the numeric value in MKS units? That can be done as follows.

```
g = SemanticInterpretation @ "acceleration of qravity" // UnitConvert
```

> `Quantity[196133/20000, ("Meters")/("Seconds")^2]`

To get the numeric value you could do

```
QuantityMagnitude[1. g]
```

or make use of how the `Quantity` is structured

```
N @ g[[1]]
```

Both give

> `9.80665`

The above does require internet access. To get by with only one such access, you can make the quantity persist in a local symbol stored in your local file system. Just evaluate

```
LocalSymbol["g"] = g
```

You can retrieve the value at any time in any Mathematica session by evaluating

```
LocalSymbol["g"]
```

You can of course use any string you like in place of "g".

Answer (score 11):

Rightly or wrongly, if the unit specification is unknown, then WA is used behind the scenes to decide if it could be interpreted as a standard unit. You can see this with the error message provided:

```
Quantity["AccelerationOfGravity"]
```

> Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification AccelerationOfGravity.
>
> Quantity["AccelerationOfGravity"]

So, you can make use of this discovery mechanism by trying to use standard English instead of some random camel-cased string. For example:

```
Quantity["acceleration due to gravity"] //InputForm
```

> Quantity[1, "StandardAccelerationOfGravity"]

Comment: I like the use of W|A here, but it also means that when W|A is down (like it seems to have been periodically recently) anything with a slightly funky `Quantity` causes the system to hang until a `::timeout` message can be emitted. Would be nice to have a quicker timeout on things like this.